# How to sum up opportunities on a contact field?

Tags: flow, process-builder, bulkification

I'm working for a non-profit organisation who wants know the total amount of opportunities related to a contact directly on the contact layout.

Moreover, they want to avoid using APEX.

So my idea by the time looks like this :

- Use the process builder to define a simple process which triggers every time an opportunity is created or edited.
- Then launch a flow that will perform the following actions :

  - Get all the contacts related to the opportunity
  - Then get all the opportunities for each contact
  - Then update and "amount" custom field on the contact

I think this will do the job but I would like to know if there is a better approach ?

Moreover, I'm pretty sure this method is not bulkproof, and so I can enjoy some trouble if I try to edit a lot of opportunities with the data loader but maybe there is a way to get it better ?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like a good approach to me. I would just give it a try.

Comment: I agree...hack that up and try...but then bulk test it to verify. Experiment with batch sizes in your bulk imports. Start with 100 and then work down from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach would work. I can offer an alternative which will make this and every other rollup easier. What we use is this app developed by Andrew Fawcett. Not sure if this counts as a trigger, but you don't have to write a line of code.

Check it out, in my opinion this is an easier approach and its reusable.

http://andyinthecloud.com/2014/04/09/new-declarative-rollup-tool-release-community-powered/

Comment: I was thinking of this...

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I'll give it a try.

I also found some kind of workaround by putting a report based on formula fields on the contact layout.

It's very cheap but a bit slow by the way.

Comment: After a few tests, it seems that this package cannot do the job in this case because I've got another object (contact role) between my parent (contact) and my child (opportunity). Anyway, it's a great tool for other situations and I will start using it right now.